# Compiling the Stanford C++ library

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, ld

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/assignments/Assignment1-linux.zip

I am self-studying this assignment for an upcoming Coursera course. I modified Warmup.cpp in 0-Warmup folder as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StanfordCPPLib/console.h"
using namespace std;

/* Constants */

const int HASH_SEED = 5381;               /* Starting point for first cycle */
const int HASH_MULTIPLIER = 33;           /* Multiplier for each cycle      */
const int HASH_MASK = unsigned(-1) >> 1;  /* All 1 bits except the sign     */

/* Function prototypes */

int hashCode(string key);

/* Main program to test the hash function */

int main() {
   string name;
   cout << "Please enter your name: "; 
   getline(cin, name); 
   int code = hashCode(name);
   cout << "The hash code for your name is " << code << "." << endl;
   return 0;
}
int hashCode(string str) {
   unsigned hash = HASH_SEED;
   int nchars = str.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < nchars; i++) {
      hash = HASH_MULTIPLIER * hash + str[i];
   }
   return (hash & HASH_MASK);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
andre@ubuntu-Andre:~/Working/Assignment1-linux/0-Warmup$ g++ Warmup.cpp -o a
/tmp/ccawOOKW.o: In function `main':
Warmup.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `_mainFlags'
Warmup.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `startupMain(int, char**)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong here?

---

UPDATE:
Got this to work now.

```
1. cd to the folder containing assignment.cpp
2. g++ assignment.cpp StanfordCPPLib/*.cpp -o a -lpthread

StanfordCPPLib/*.cpp this part indicate that everything in the library will be compiled,
-pthread will link pthread.h, which is used by several utilities in the Stanford library.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random `"StanfordCPPLib/console.h"` I found on the net includes fun code like:

```
#if CONSOLE_FLAG | GRAPHICS_FLAG

#define main main(int argc, char **argv) { \
extern int _mainFlags; \
_mainFlags = GRAPHICS_FLAG + CONSOLE_FLAG; \
return startupMain(argc, argv); \
} \
int Main

extern int startupMain(int argc, char **argv);
```

So your `main()` function is apparently really a function called `Main()` that is ultimately called by some support function, `startupMain()`, that's in a library your instructor should provide.

You need to link to that library. Your assignment or course notes should have instructions on how to do that and where the library comes from.

Comment: Thank you! I've located the startupMain() which can be found in Assignment1-linux/0-Warmup/StanfordCPPLib/platform.cpp on line 954. Unfortunately I am a self-learner and cannot find any instruction on how to link them up on the course website. Would you mind instruct me on how to link the files together?

Comment: cannot get the linking working properly so I workaround by removing the console.h header.

Comment: @user14042: that's probably a good solution for this particular program, but you'll probably need to figure out how to incorporate the library for subsequent assignments and/or because it might be part of their mechanism for grading assignments (they may have a version of the library that provides metrics or tests specific assignment requirements for example by injecting errors).

Comment: Hmm, that concerns me, but I'll see how everything works out for the subsequent assignments. Thanks again.